# Display Associated Lookup Field on Newform.aspx immediately after selection

Tags: lookup-column, custom-form

Here is my scenario:

I have List A called Case Info.  In it, I am assigning a Case ID based on the YY-XXXX format (so 17-0001 is the first for 2017).  In this list I define what firm the case is assigned to via a lookup to a firms list, and then a workflow copies this lookup to an additional text field.  We also define a quick synopsis of the case by name via text.

On List B, called Employee Time, we have our employees record the time that they work on various tasks for the case so that we can bill the client accordingly for services rendered.  This list has a lookup to Case Info for Case ID.  I am also pulling in the Firm and Case Name fields to be recorded on the entry for reference points.  My team has requested that after they select the Case ID on the newform.aspx page, that the fields for Case Name and Firm show up immediately so that they can be sure that they are entering data on the right case, without the need to then go back and edit after saving.

Is this possible?  Addon/Third Party products are ok as long as they will fit the bill.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look for the SPServices jquery library on Codeplex (I think it's in Github now too). It's a jquery library for SharePoint list forms, among other things.

It has a SPDisplayRelatedInfo call that will do this for you.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I am not very strong (and by that I mean its very new to me) in jquery.  Could you by chance explain how I would use that function?